# SetState after Get Request React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, get

I have a handleSubmit method:

```
state = {
    code: null,
    participant: {},
    participantNotFound: false,
};

handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {code} = this.state;

    axios.get(`/api/participant/${code}`)
        .then((response) => {
            const participant = response.data.participant;
            console.log(participant)
            this.setState({participant})
        })
        .catch(() => this.setState({participantNotFound: true}));

    console.log(this.state.participant) // THIS IS STILL EMPTY
};
```

That triggers when the form is submitted:

```
<form method="POST" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <div className="ui action input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter code" name="code"/>

        <select className="ui compact selection dropdown" onChange={event => this.setState({selectedOption: event.target.value})}>
            <option value="participate">Participate!</option>
            <option value="check_status">Check status</option>
        </select>

        <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I put a console.log, and it outputs the **participant** correctly, but it doesn't set the participant to the participant that I get from my response.

I have other code after this that checks if participant exists or not, but it doesn't work because the participant never gets set.

Why is this?

Comment: `this` might not be what you think it is

Comment: @SterlingArcher When I console.log(this), it prints my class correctly. I thought this was the issue, but the fat arrow should be taking care of this.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean, but `setState({participantNotFound: true})` couldn't update if didn't have an error because you put them in the catch

Comment: did you check if `render` or `componentDidUpdate` gets called? is it a PureComponent? are you 100% sure it does not update?

Comment: how do you check, why claim it doesn't work?

Comment: @xadm I put a console.log(this.state) inside the render() which should have been triggered after I updated the state, and a participant is still an empty object.

Comment: Try checking the state in your `render` rather than immediately after update state

Comment: so are you using PureComponent? you should add more parts of your code to make it easier for us to help.

Comment: It is not a Pure component. I think I know what the problem is. I thought it didn't set it because I consoled.logged just after the axios.get, but this is an async function, so I suppose by the time I try to console.log, it is too early? When I do a console.log in a render, it shows the correct state.

Comment: i thought that you did console.log in the render function already, and it did not show the correct state?

Comment: oh...now i see it...you put that console log after axios...yeah....that cannot work, it´s async. it would not even work directly after setState.

Answer (score 2):

It most likely gets set, but you don´t check it correctly. Version with `async`/`await`:

```
handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {code} = this.state;

    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`/api/participant/${code}`);
        const participant = response.data.participant;
        this.setState({participant});
    } catch (err) {
        this.setState({participantNotFound: true}))
    }
};
```

Keep in mind that you will not be able to detect the new state right after `setState`. You can check if it is set correctly in `componentDidUpdate` or `render`, for example. Alternatively, you can check the new state in the callback function of `setState`:

```
this.setState({participant}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.participant);
});
```

Remember, `axios` is asynchronous, `setState` is asynchronous.